# setHTTPMethod:@"POST" not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, post

i try many solutions from stackoverflow to fix this trouble, but no luck.
My trouble is setHTTPMethod not works thats always use GET method.
My code is:

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverAPIUrl]];
NSMutableData *requestBody = [NSMutableData data];
NSString *boundary = @"ljlkjlkkljlk98jjmnj";

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setCachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData];

[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary] forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

[requestBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[requestBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",@"file",@"file.gz"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[requestBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[requestBody appendData:[self gzipData:returnData]];

NSMutableArray *keys=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *vals=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//post vars
[keys addObject:@"postvariable"];
[vals addObject:@"kjasdhfklsadjfhsajdkfhasdfjhsadfkjsadfhskdfjhjhf"];
//add post vars to body

for(i=0;i<[keys count];i++)
{
    [requestBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; \r\n\r\n%@",boundary,
                              [keys objectAtIndex:i],
                              [vals objectAtIndex:i]
                              ] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
//add post vars to body
[requestBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:requestBody];

NSData *answer = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse: &response error: nil ];

NSLog(@"server answer:%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:answer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

PHP on server

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["getjob"]))
{

}
else 
{
    foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) {
        echo "$name: $value\n";
    }

    var_dump($_FILES);
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo file_exists($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    echo "ok";  
}
```

What i have:

```
REMOTE_PORT: 57688
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD: GET
QUERY_STRING: 
REQUEST_URI: /dcapi/
```

Thats server answer just returns $_SERVER variables. I always getting GET method. But i always use POST.

I tried many solutions from stackoverflow with no luck:

1. http://kemal.co/index.php/2012/02/fetching-data-with-getpost-methods-by-using-nsurlconnection/ - i just download sources. With no result.
2. [HTTP Post Request in Objective-C Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480689/http-post-request-in-objective-c-not-working)
   not works.
3. [Upload file not working vie HTTP Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744045/upload-file-not-working-vie-http-post)
   not works.
4. [POST from iPhone to PhP not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454231/post-from-iphone-to-php-not-working)
   not works.

Comment: Can you please modify your code example so that it is the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Have you verified the network request with Charles Proxy?

Comment: Erm, doesn't "if(isset($_REQUEST["getjob"]))" mean "if the client DID send a parameter with name "getjob", execute code, otherwise execute code in the else block" ? Maybe you need to set a value for parameter "getjob". Also, is that "What i have" block of text the server response or your Xcode request console log? Perhaps your server only accept "GET" request for that particular API endpoint URL and you're trying to give it a POST request.

Comment: I try send POST via html form - works fine - i see REQUEST_METHOD: POST. I don't send getjob parameter via POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I solve it.
Thats because i set end of url as folder/ but executing file is in folder/index.php.
And i getting 301 redirect for my post request and only get result from second request as GET.